# Can't set response headers in express

Tags: node.js, express, header

I can't set my header what is wrong ?

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.header('myHeader','ok');
   /*
   even
   res.set('myHeader','ok');
   tried but there is no difference
   */
  res.redirect('/x');
  })

app.get('/x',(req,res)=>{
  res.send(req.headers);
  })

app.listen(3000);
```

and when I navigate to `localhost:3000` I get the same result every time.

This is the result :

```
{
host: "localhost:3000",
connection: "keep-alive",
upgrade-insecure-requests: "1",
user-agent: "XX",
accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
accept-encoding: "gzip, deflate, br",
accept-language: "en-US,en;q=0.9",
cookie: "XX"
}
```

and as you can see `myHeader` doesn't appear on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Here's the solution, **when we make a redirect actually we are making a new http request**. 
so in my case the `req` which used in `/x` path is different from the `/` path.